# For Gutenberg block editor, How do I use media query to display smaller sized background images on a mobile version of a site(otter plugin)

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries, wordpress-gutenberg

I installed the Otter plugin, which offers a collection of page-building blocks, including the section block that can be set to have different columns for displaying various contents. The Otter plugin also adds the functionality of 'custom CSS' and 'additional CSS class,' visible in settings (on the right side of the screen) when editing a page.

My page consists of different sections, and each section has a background image. I tried using a media query to display a smaller size of a background image on the mobile view of the site. However, when I updated the changes made, all the background images on the page disappeared.

First, from the dashboard, I clicked on media and uploaded a smaller background image to the library. Next, I chose a page to edit and clicked on a section to display the smaller background image (on the right side of the page are the settings with custom CSS and advanced options).

Under the advanced options is a text field for 'additional CSS class.' This is where I typed in a new CSS class, 'bgmobile.' After that, I typed the CSS code below in the 'custom CSS' field and clicked the update button.

```css
@media(max-width:768px){
  .bgmobile{
    Background-image:url(‘image-url-from-media’)
  }
}
```

I expected the smaller background image to display on mobile devices, but instead, all the background images on all sections disappeared from the page (both on mobile and desktop devices), leaving only text.

Comment: We can’t tell what you are doing wrong without more information. Please read this description of [how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).